# Latest version of chrome 63.0 is not supported in library Google One Tap

Tags: google-identity

I am using the latest version of chrome Version 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit) on OSX High Sierra 10.13.2. Everything was working okay on the previous version of Google Chrome, but with new update I get error

```
unsupportedBrowser
```

I checked if my JS is wrong but apparently not because it's working on Safari and Firefox without as expected, but when it comes to Chrome it's not.

I am using this library https://smartlock.google.com/client

Comment: It should be working (I verified on a live site myself with Chrome 63). Can you reproduce the issue, do you have any more info about the site?

Comment: Also check that you are not using mobile browser or user-agent emulation (the iOS device emulation in devtools is not a valid user-agent)

Comment: We are now logging new warnings in the console, could you try again and see whether something is logged?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on http? I had a similar issue and it started working when I switched my url to https(obviously your website should be already on https for this to work). I had, by mistake, typed in the http url of my website.

Comment: Yeah, you need to have a secure connection (tls, ssl) in order to use this library.